# How to rename external file from actual cwd?

Tags: python

I want to rename a file located externally regarding my actual working directory but i just want to use the relative path from this and not the absolute path to the file.

More precisely, if `os.getcwd()` yells `"/home/jscherman/Documents/Workspace/my-project"` and i want to rename a file located at "/home/jscherman/Documents/Workspace/my_file", i want to accomplish the equivalent to `rm ../my_file`.

To do this, i tried with

```
import os
os.rename("../my_file", "../my_file_edited")
```

But this is throwing

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to do this in a general way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want `os.path.abspath`.

See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath).